# "Due to lack of common sense" vs. "For lack of common sense"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, conjunctions

> 1. **Due to** lack of common sense, he cannot succeed in life.
> 2. **For** lack of common sense, he cannot succeed in life.

How do both differ from each other? I believe I can use both of them in this sentence. Suggestions please.

Comment: Both can be used to mean because of.  I think they can be used interchangeably in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As @Khan says, yes they are both used in this sense as synonyms of **because of** and both sentences work.

In common speech, **Because of** would more likely be used. **Due to** would be appropriate for formal speech, while **For** is slightly more poetic.

But they certainly all mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: My book says in the sentence correction part that For should come in place of Due to . So, in general we can say both but grammatically there might be some difference.  I am not sure what right now, but I will find out.